# Javascript How do i check every 5 seconds if a specific key was clicked?

Tags: javascript

In this case, how do i check every 5 seconds if the right arrow button was clicked? Here what i've tried. It only works once and never checks again. What am i doing wrong?

```
setInterval(KeyPressed, 5000);

window.onkeydown = KeyPressed;

function KeyPressed(k) {

    if (k.keyCode == 39) {
        alert("Right Arrow");
    }

}
```

Comment: Pressed and released or pressed and held?

Comment: maybe you always want to respond to any keyPress event but only want to handle the "Right Arrow" key-code every 5 seconds in case it does occur. In this case you might do a search on "throttle" and/or "debounce".

Comment: You don't need `setInterval`, the `onkeydown` will trigger automatically every time a key is pressed. Tried it and it works, as long as your window has focus.

Comment: That is because k is undefined and k.keyCode throws a console error and stops after 5 seconds.

Comment: Why do you want to do this? Sounds like a design problem to me. Perhaps if you could add a bit of background as to what you are trying to achieve we could solve the X of your *seems-to-be* X-Y problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perhaps this?

Check if the last key that was clicked is the arrow

```js
var lastKey = "", tId = setInterval(testKey, 5000);

window.onkeydown = KeyPressed;

function KeyPressed(k) {
  lastKey = k.keyCode;
}
function testKey() {
  if (lastKey == 39) {
    console.log("Arrow pressed as last key in the last 5 secs");
    lastKey=""; // clear it for next time
  }
}
```

Check if the arrow has been clicked in the last 5 seconds

```js
var lastKey = "", tId = setInterval(testKey, 5000), arrow = "";

window.onkeydown = KeyPressed;

function KeyPressed(k) {
  lastKey = k.keyCode;
  if (lastKey == 39) {
    arrow = new Date();
    console.log("pressed arrow");
  }  
}
function testKey() {
  if (arrow) {
    console.log("Arrow pressed at least once in the last 5 secs - at "+arrow);
  }
  arrow="";
}
```

Comment: Also if I press right arrow and then something else, the right arrow is not remembered.